# Unable to authenticate Client, Error: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, asp.net-identity, azure-ad-b2c

I have a problem with my .Net Core API where I use Azure AD B2C (bearer tokens).App works just fine, but I also wanted to write  unit test for example for simple GET. I get the following error while running test:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Error while copying content to a stream.
---- System.IO.IOException : 
-------- System.InvalidOperationException : IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'.
------------ System.IO.IOException : IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'.
---------------- System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Ttpsc.DotNetInternship.SandwichApp.Tests.InMemory.Base.BaseTest.Get[T](String endpoint, T parameter) in C:\...SandwichApp.Tests\InMemory\Base\BaseTest.cs:line 90
   at C:\..SandwichApp.Tests.ControllersTest.GroupsControllerTest.GetGroups_GetAllGroups() in C:\..SandwichApp.Tests\ControllersTest\GroupsControllerTest.cs:line 20
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseStream.CheckAborted()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer)
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.HttpContextBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
```

**BaseTest.CS** (Create TestServer and HttpClient.Client)

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Flurl.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Ttpsc.DotNetInternship.SandwichApp.Tests.InMemory.Base
{
    public abstract class BaseTest : IDisposable
    {
        private bool _disposed;

        protected BaseTest()
        {
            Server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseStartup<Startup>());

            Services = Server.Host.Services;


            Client = Server.CreateClient();
            //Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                .Accept
                .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }

        protected TestServer Server { get; set; }

        protected HttpClient Client { get; set; }

        protected IServiceProvider Services { get; set; }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }




        protected Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string endpoint)
        {
            return Get<string>(endpoint, null);
        }

        protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get<T>(string endpoint, T parameter)
        {
            var tt = await GetToken();

            var jo = JObject.Parse(tt);
            var token = jo["access_token"].ToString();


            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);



            var url = string.Concat(endpoint, parameterQuery);
            Console.WriteLine(url);


            return await Client.GetAsync(url);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
                if (disposing)
                {
                    Client?.Dispose();
                    Server?.Dispose();
                }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**GroupsControllerTest.CS** (Unit test)

```
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Ttpsc.DotNetInternship.SandwichApp.Tests.InMemory.Base;
using Xunit;

namespace Ttpsc.DotNetInternship.SandwichApp.Tests.ControllersTest
{
    public class GroupsControllerTest : BaseTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task GetGroups_GetAllGroups()
        {
            // Arrange

            var url = "api/groups";
            var expected = HttpStatusCode.OK;

            // Act

            var response = await Get(url);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it is trying to fetch the metadata JSON document. If you want to run the tests without auth, you could configure the tests to run in an environment where auth does not get configured. Otherwise you'll have to configure it properly so it can fetch the metadata.

Comment: Set the following flag to get to the actual error: IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; (just remember to remove this before releasing your code to production)

Comment: Great suggestion to set IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII to true. In my case it turned out my configuration was missing a `/` resulting in a endpoint like 
`https://login.microsoftonline.com6a5cc1f7-159d-4b3c-b318-2410c5eddc9e/.well-known/openid-configuration`

instead of: 

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/6a5cc1f7-159d-4b3c-b318-2410c5eddc9e/.well-known/openid-configuration`


And yes, that's just a random guid in this example ;)